# How to allocate IP address in VPC to RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have an RDS instance started in a DB Subnet Group in my VPC. This instance has an endpoint of the form `someDatabase-db-small.abcd1234.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`.

**How does one allocate to this instance an IP address in the VPC subnet `10.0.0.0/24`?**

Comment: The DNS endpoint will (to my knowledge) resolve to the internal IP from within Amazon's network.  It's not recommended to use the internal IP's, as they can change without notice (Multi AZ actions, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instance will already have an IP address in that range allocated. Use something like 'dig' to lookup the IP address of the endpoint from *inside* of the VPC and you will get back an IP address from your VPC subnet.