# Amazon AWS - How can I change the Private IP of a Network Interface linked to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an RDS DB Instance linked to a VPC.

This created a Network Interface and automatically assigned an internal IP: 10.0.10.65

I want to change this IP address to 10.0.10.15

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike EC2 instances, allocating a private ip of an RDS instance is not possible, this has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535242/how-to-allocate-ip-address-in-vpc-to-rds-instance).

The recommended method to access an instance is through its endpoint:

> Please note that, we strongly recommend you use the DNS Name to connect to your DB Instance as the underlying IP address can change (e.g., during a failover).

Comment: If we use the DNS name and a EC2 instance access it, will the call go through the Internet or will be local as a call with the private IP would be?

Comment: The call will automatically translate to the internal IP

Answer (score 3):

Users do not have control of the IP address assigned to RDS instances. You can choose the subnet but cannot assign a static IP address like you can for EC2 instances in a VPC.